# MVC Express + MySQL return TypeError: Cannot read property 'showAll' of undefined

Tags: mysql, node.js, model-view-controller

I got a problem with a site im working. I have a model.js a controller.js and routes.js

model

```
const mysql = require("mysql2");

class Article {
  Firstname;
  LastName;
  Age;
  id;

  static findAll() {
    const connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host: "localhost",
      user: "root",
      password: "root",
      database: "ha_test",
    });

    connection.query("SELECT * FROM users", (err, articles) => {
      if (err) return res.send(err);
      return articles;
    })
  }
}
module.exports = Article;
```

Controller

```
const Article = require("../models/Article");

function showAll(req, res) {
  Article.findAll(function (articles) {
    res.render("articles", { articles });
  })
};

module.exports = showAll();
```

Routes

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const articleController = require("./controller/articleController");
router.use(express.json());
router.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


router.get("/",
  articleController.showAll())

module.exports = router;
```

When I use nodemon index.js it shows me TypeError: Cannot read property 'showAll' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Your controller actually exports the invocation of your `showAll()` function - which returns `undefined`.

So your `articleController` variable in your routes file is equal to `undefined`, and when you call `articleController.showAll()`, you try to access a `showAll` property on the `undefined` value - which is not a valid operation and throw the error you're seeing.

Edit: if you want to export the `showAll()` function, just export a reference to it rather than actually calling it:

```
module.exports = showAll
```

Then when importing your module, you will get a direct reference to this function

```
const showAll = require("./controller/articleController");
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks!, so, what should I export? I can not understand it

Comment: Now it shows me Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]

Comment: You most likely called router.get("/", showAll()) instead of router.get("/", showAll). Again, you just pass your router a reference to your function, and it will take care of calling it when relevant - ie when when a request for the route comes in.